# How to add a new Object into an Array of a particular Object in MongoDB using Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Here is my model and already have some documents in the DataBase.

I want to push a new **Object** into `like_count` Array of an existing post document, where `postId` will be matched with the given value.

I am using ***Mongoose*** for the first time. I have searched but didn't find a use-case like this one. Can't understood how to write the logic. Need help.

Also, tell me is it ok how I defined `Users` Model or should I use **Sub-Document** for those Object of Array??

```
const Users = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: { type: String, unique: true },
    recent_posts: [
      {
        postId: String,
        posted_at_timestamp: Number,
        like_count: [
          {
            count: Number,
            created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
          }
        ],
        comment_count: [
          {
            count: Number,
            created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$push` and `arrayFilters` operator to achieve this:

```js
await User.updateOne({
  'recent_posts.postId': postId
}, {
  $push: {
    'recent_posts.$[elem].like_count': newLikeCountObject
  }
}, {
  arrayFilters: [{'elem.postId': postId}]
})
```

Comment: @Abid - Please post a separate answer with your own enhancements, rather than attempting to edit someone else's answer with your additions.

Comment: You can use async await to achieve what you want.